# SFML 2.1 C++ documentation - is sf::Event really a union?

Tags: c++, sfml

Upon reading SFML 2.1's documentation I stumbled across this:

> Before dealing with events, it is important to understand what the sf::Event type is, and how to correctly use it. **sf::Event is a union**, which means that only one of its member is valid at a time (remember your C++ lesson: all the members of a union share the same memory space).

However upon inspection of sf::Event's declaration I came across this:

```
    class Event
    {
    public :

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        /// \brief Size events parameters (Resized)
        ///
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        struct SizeEvent
        {
            unsigned int width;  ///< New width, in pixels
            unsigned int height; ///< New height, in pixels
        }; 
.....
 EventType type; ///< Type of the event
....
```

sf::Event cannot be a union since, sf::Event::EventType for example, does not share a memory region with any of the other members of sf::Event, as is clearly defined in the definition.

The only union declaration I see is the following, taken again from the class definition:

```
union
    {
        SizeEvent            size;            ///< Size event parameters (Event::Resized)
        KeyEvent             key;             ///< Key event parameters (Event::KeyPressed, Event::KeyReleased)
        TextEvent            text;            ///< Text event parameters (Event::TextEntered)
        MouseMoveEvent       mouseMove;       ///< Mouse move event parameters (Event::MouseMoved)
        MouseButtonEvent     mouseButton;     ///< Mouse button event parameters (Event::MouseButtonPressed, Event::MouseButtonReleased)
        MouseWheelEvent      mouseWheel;      ///< Mouse wheel event parameters (Event::MouseWheelMoved)
        JoystickMoveEvent    joystickMove;    ///< Joystick move event parameters (Event::JoystickMoved)
        JoystickButtonEvent  joystickButton;  ///< Joystick button event parameters (Event::JoystickButtonPressed, Event::JoystickButtonReleased)
        JoystickConnectEvent joystickConnect; ///< Joystick (dis)connect event parameters (Event::JoystickConnected, Event::JoystickDisconnected)
    };
```

So am I missing something or is it just a genuine mistake in the documentation?

Comment: Here is a reference: http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/window-events.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It is not a union**, and due to the enum type member not even a union-like class

9.5.8

> A union-like class is a union or a class that has an anonymous union
>   as a direct member. A union-like class X has a set of variant members.

You can check this for yourself:

```
class IsUnion {
  public:

  struct struct1 {
      float tt;
  };

  struct struct2 {
      float tt;
  };

  enum EventType { no, yes };

  EventType type; 

  union
  {
      struct1 obj;
      struct2 obj2;
  };

};

int main() {

    cout << is_union<IsUnion>::value; // 0
}
```

[Example](http://ideone.com/vdRwUX)

anyway the bulk of the class consists of an anonymous union, I believe the documentation wanted to simplify this assumption and make it easy for the reader to understand.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although it may simplify things it can also confuse readers, such as when analyzing memory allocations. Bad segment of documentation is you ask me.